How to remove the annoying bue box around icons and folders when you hovering around it or click on it?
I spent the whole day trying to find this. On Windows 10 when you move cursor over folders or icons it get blue selection box around. It can be pretty annoying when you have to list a lot of icons or folders.
I tried to search for answer on many other forums, I tried asking Windows support, I asked everyone I know and no one, literally no one had an answer. I even used third-party apps to change it, like openshell and windowsblinds. It starts to look like impossible task.
This is screenshot of old question on this forum, it had somewhat "answer" leading to another forum, but seems like its outdated for Windows 10:




Please include a screenshot of your own issue in the question. Please list the specific things you have tried, all of them, in the question itself. Use the EDIT button to improve and complete your question.

Windows itself does not offer this unless you indeed go Classic View, or high Contrast view (which is essentially classic view).
This is basically because when you select a file, Windows needs a way to show you what your selection is, and this blue box is how it does this.
If you want to change this, you will need to resort to any form of skinning the OS manually. This effectively means, that you need to buy a program such as Stardock WindowBlinds.
There are also programs that can change the look of explorer to former versions of windows, such as Classic Start. While it may seem that this is only for the start menu, the start menu is part of explorer, and as such some of these solutions not only allow changing the start menu, but explorer as well. It will not have as much control as WindowBlinds, where you can literally change the color, the transparancy, and everything else.
